# Column Chart in Google Charts is displaying bars 10 times proper height

Tags: google-visualization

I can't figure out why, I've triple checked that I'm passing in the right values.  When I hover over any of the bars it displays the right data, but every single one of them displays at 10x scale on the graph and I can't figure out why.  Here's my code if it helps:

```
var dashboard2 = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard'));

var control2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
    // Filter by the date axis.
        'filterColumnIndex': 0,
        'ui': {
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'chartOptions': {
                'chartArea': {'width': '80%'},
                'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
            },
            // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
            // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
            'chartView': {
                'columns': [0, 1, 14]
            },
            // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
            'minRangeSize': 259200000
        }
    },
    // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
    'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2012, 11, 7), 'end': new Date()}}
});

var chart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ComboChart',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
        // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
        'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '80%'},
        'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
        'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 400}},
        'title': 'Sales Made by Affiliate Name',
        'seriesType': "bars",
        'series': {0: {type: "line"}, 13: {type: "line"}},
        'isStacked': true
    },
    // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.
    'view': {
        'columns': [
        {
            'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
                return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 0);
            },
            'type': 'string'
        }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
    }
});

var jsonData2 = $.ajax({
    url: "getData.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server
var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData2);

dashboard2.bind(control2, chart2);
dashboard2.draw(data2);
```

**Edit:** Here's a small bit of the data at the very beginning, because I don't want to give out our data, but I suppose it might be necessary to get an idea for what is being passed in.  I cut out the starting bracket for readability:

```
"cols":[ {"id":"","label":"Date","pattern":"","type":"date"}, {"id":"","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"andersce99","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"sojourn","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"warriorplus","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"potpie queen","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"60minuteaffiliate","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"bob voges","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"Grayth","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"TiffanyDow","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"AmandaT","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"Gaz Cooper","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"Sam England","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"Matthew Olson","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"Average Per Day Over Time","pattern":"","type":"number"} ],
"rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,7)","f":null},{"v":"387","f":null},{"v":"19","f":null},{"v":"275","f":null},{"v":"8","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"35","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"21","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"11","f":null},{"v":"6","f":null},{"v":"387","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,8)","f":null},{"v":"98","f":null},{"v":"11","f":null},{"v":"39","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"15","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"9","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"6","f":null},{"v":"242.5","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,9)","f":null},{"v":"58","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"16","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"10","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"9","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"181","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,10)","f":null},{"v":"196","f":null},{"v":"5","f":null},{"v":"8","f":null},{"v":"126","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"35","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"184.75","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,11)","f":null},{"v":"76","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"5","f":null},{"v":"17","f":null},{"v":"30","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"163","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,12)","f":null},{"v":"48","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"5","f":null},{"v":"9","f":null},{"v":"20","f":null},{"v":"7","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"143.833333333","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,13)","f":null},{"v":"21","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"5","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"126.285714286","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,14)","f":null},{"v":"12","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"112","f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Date(2012,11,15)","f":null},{"v":"8","f":null},{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"100.444444444","f":null}]}
```

Comment: I tried dividing all my data by 10 and it just appears at the scale I think it would properly appear at if it were 1/10 the size.  This becomes more frustrating the more I work on it?

Comment: Post the JSON returned by your AJAX query and I'll look into it.

Comment: Well, that's a /huge/ amount of data, and I don't want to give it away, but I'll give a small sample I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is formatted incorrectly: numbers need to be stored as numbers in the JSON, not as strings.  As an example, this:

```
{"v":"387","f":null}
```

should be like this:

```
{"v":387,"f":null}
```

If you are using PHP's `json_encode` function to build the JSON, you can add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as an argument to the function call to output the numbers properly:

```
json_encode($myData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: I'm just echoing out stuff is all.  Good to know.

Comment: That totally fixed it!  Thanks!